# Formatting the output result using Selenium Python to show text in a single line

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I have the following sample html code, for which I am trying to scrape the data:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="firstdigitinside">
        <span class="firstdigit">
            <span class="firstdigithere>1
            </span>
        </span>
        <span class="seconddigit">
            <span class="seconddigithere>2
            </span>
        </span>
        <span class="thirddigit">
            <span class="thirddigithere>3
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Code is as Follows:

```
threedigits = driver.find_element("xpath", ".//div[@class='main']").text
print(threedigits, sep="", end="")
```

My Output is as follows:

```
1
2
3
```

The result I am trying to achieve is supposed to look like this:

```
123
```

The output result is supposed to be in a single row without any spaces in between.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one

`threedigits = ''.join(threedigits.split())`

or

`threedigits = threedigits.replace('\n', '')`